# why is a asp.net webapp outputtype classlibrary?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was under the impression that a class library cannot run on it's own but when i created a asp.net (framework) webapp using the template provided in visual studio i see that it's output type is class library. What is the reason for this and how this work opposed to a windows or console application which generate an .exe file?

Comment: Are you talking about legacy ASP.NET instead of ASP.NET Core, just to clarify?

Comment: yes i'm talking about framework sorry should have specified

Comment: While it's been a *very* long time since I've written non-Core ASP.NET, isn't an ASP.NET app effectively a plugin called by an existing web server (e.g. IIS or IIS Express) rather than standalone? That would explain the difference...

Comment: oh ok that makes sense so essentialy iis will load the classlib library and IIS is actually the executing program ?

Comment: The fact of having a class object in code behind is quite much gives and allows one with great ease to write code in c# or vb.net, and have full intel-sense and a object model that works VERY nice with .net. So this also means that with great ease you can drop into a web page with great ease data "aware" controls, be that a simple drop down list (combo box), or that of a complex grid or listview.